# Identify the limit or show that it does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis

**Definition 1.** The sequence $(a_n)$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ converges to the limit $x\in X$ provided that for each positive real number $\epsilon$, there exists a natural number N so that whenever $n>N$,

$$d(a_n,x)<\epsilon$$

When $(a_n)$ converges to $x$, we may write $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=x$ or just $a_n\rightarrow x$.

Just doing some practice problems so I was hoping to get some guidance in case I was approaching the problem incorrectly. We are to use **Definition 1, with proof**.

Problem (1): $a_n=3$ for $n\geq 1$.

**Solution:** Let $\epsilon >0$. Now, we choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. We consider $n>N$. Then,

$$d(a_n,0)=|3-0|
=|3|$$
$$3<\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$$

Comment: So just what is your  question?

Comment: "I was hoping to get some guidance in case I was approaching the problem incorrectly."

Comment: Therefore, is it incorrect or am I going about it the right way?

Comment: What is this _it_ of which you speak?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to show that $a_n\to0$, which is clearly false since $a_n=3$ for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: If your sequence is constant, why do you think that the limit is zero?

Comment: The limit is clearly not zero. If $a_n=3$ for all $n\geq 1$, then the limit is just 3, since it is constant.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and pointing it out, @Clayton. I must have got confused on the way it was represented. First time seeing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be the limit of a constant sequence? The constant itself, of course.

In the case of a constant sequence you can choose $N_{\epsilon}$ independent of $\epsilon$:

- Let $a_n=3$ for $n\geq 1$ and let $\epsilon > 0$.
- $\Rightarrow$ For all $n \geq N=1$ you have $|a_n-3| = |3-3| = 0 < \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for writing out all the steps. I was just having a brain fart at the moment, but this helped me follow along. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ryan You are welcome. :-)